# Do I need to explicitly pass a combobox as a reference in a function, or will the compiler do this for me?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, reference

In C#.NET (WinForms), I have a function that fills up an existing combobox on a form with the result of a query:

```
FillComboBox("SELECT Value FROM Table", comboBox1);

public void FillComboBox(string query, ComboBox combobox)
    {
        cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            combobox.Items.Add(reader[0]);
        }
        combobox.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
```

The above appears to work fine, however I also have the option of using a reference, as shown below:

```
FillComboBox("SELECT Value FROM Table", ref comboBox1);

public void FillComboBox(string query, ref ComboBox combobox)
    {
        cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            combobox.Items.Add(reader[0]);
        }
        combobox.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
```

Again, both functions work identically - however is it more efficient or safer in any way to use the latter one, passing the combobox as a reference? Or is the compiler doing this implicitly anyway in the first function?

Comment: No, the second one implies a different concept. The second one means that you intend to change the reference not to add items to the combobox class.

Comment: Thanks. Which is the most appropriate/efficient one for my above scenario? I assumed that the 2nd one would be the most efficient, as by using a reference, it would work on the actual combobox I intend to fill, whereas the 1st one would first create a new instance of a combobox in memory, which after it's filled would be then copied into the one I want to fill on screen (that i'm passing as the parameter).

Comment: To get a good understanding about parameter passing, I highly recommend [Jon's article](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html)

Comment: The both codes are equivalent as Windows Form Controls are reference type by nature. That means regardless whether you pass them by ref parameter or not, they are still passed as ref parameters.

Comment: Ahh thank you! Is there a list anywhere of what other types or controls are passed as reference by default?

Comment: I think I made a mistake by saying Windows Client Controls are passed as ref parameter. Again, Windows Form Controls are reference type by nature. That means their actual values are stored in the heap inside the memory rather than the stack. However, their reference addresses are stored in the stack. So what happened when you pass the control as a value type, you are passing the actual control address which is stored in the stack. this is way it behaves like you have passed them as reference parameter. Whatever changes happen inside the method affect the control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second example, while working, is wrong and misleading of your intentions.

A reference variable (suppose we have declared it as `ComboBox cbx = new ComboBox();` in the calling code of this method) holds a simple value that represents the memory address where the instance of a combobox is stored. The same variable (`cbx`) is allocated on the heap and has its own address where it stores the address of the combobox instance returned by the `new ComboBox()` call.

When, in the first example, you pass the `cbx` variable to the FillCombo method  a new variable local to the method is created on the stack and the value of `cbx` is stored there (the memory address of the combobox instance).
So now you are able to change the combobox properties freely and the caller see the changes made to the combobox data.

When you use the ref keyword things changes. The FillCombo method, in the second example, still creates a local variable named `combobox` but this local receives the address of `cbx`, not its value. The intent here is to create a new instance of a ComboBox calling something like `combobox = new ComboBox();` (different address for a different instance) and use the address value of the passed variable to let the passed variable 'point' to the new instance.

From a point of view of performance I think that there is no measurable difference if any, but the presence of the ref keyword is just misleading.

Good reference articles are:

[C#Concepts: Value Types vs Reference Types](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx)  from **Joseph Albahari**
[Parameter Passing in C#](http://yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html) from **Jon Skeet**

Comment: I'm confused, could you break it down a bit more if possible?

Comment: The referenced links (the second one in particular) have a more in depth discussion of this concept. Suffice to say that your first example doesn't create a new ComboBox but passes the memory address of the combo instance created through the designer (or code). The second example allows you to create a new instance of the combo and let the calling code see the new instance. But you are not using this 'feature' so, in this terms, it is misleading of your intentions

Comment: Thanks. I was under the impression from that article by Jon Skeet, that if I used the ref keyword, it would work on the actual instance of that variable, whereas if I didn't, it would create a new instance, but it seems like actually it's closer to the other way around, cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

In the first code sample you pass a copy of `combobox1` reference. So you can access properties of `comboBox1`, because `combobox` parameter refers to the same object as `comboBox1`. If you try to make new object: `combobox = new ComboBox()` - you will not change `comboBox1`, because `combobox` is a copy of it.
In the second code sample you pass `comboBox1` reference (not a copy). You also can access `comboBox1` properties like in the first code sample, but now you can change `comboBox1`, because you passed straight reference: `combobox = new ComboBox()` will be the same as `comboBox1 = new ComboBox()`.

Comment: But I don't want to create a copy of combobox1. I want to add the results into the original instance of combobox1 (that's already created in the windows forms designer).

Comment: @JohnBergqvist Your two code samples work identical. I think, it would be better to use first code sample, because it prevents from modifying original object, just in case.

Comment: But modifying the original object is exactly what I want to do, by adding the items to it.

Comment: @JohnBergqvist You are not modifying object - you are modifying it's properties `Items` and `SelectedIndex`. If you don't need to make `combobox = new ComboBox()` use first code sample. `ref` parameter is used, when you need to modify an object, not his properties and fields.